# How is the output h_n of an RNN (nn.LSTM, nn.GRU, etc.) in PyTorch structured?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, pytorch

The docs say

> **h_n** of shape (num_layers * num_directions, batch, hidden_size): tensor containing the hidden state for t = seq_len

Now, the **batch** and **hidden_size** dimensions are pretty much self-explanatory. The first dimension remains a mystery, though.

I assume, that the hidden states of all "last cells" of all layers are included in this output. But then what is the index of, for example, the hidden state of the "last cell" in the "uppermost layer"? `h_n[-1]`? `h_n[0]`?

Is the output affected by the `batch_first` option?

Answer (score 10):

The implementation of LSTM and GRU in pytorch automatically includes the possibility of stacked layers of LSTMs and GRUs.

You give this with the keyword argument `nn.LSTM(num_layers=num_layers)`. `num_layers` is the number of stacked LSTMs (or GRUs) that you have. The default value is 1, which gives you the basic LSTM.

`num_directions` is either 1 or 2. It is 1 for normal LSTMs and GRUs, and it is 2 for bidirectional RNNs.

So in your case, you probably have a simple LSTM or GRU so the value of `num_layers * num_directions` would then be one.

`h_n[0]` is the hidden state of the bottom-most layer (the one which takes in the input), and `h_n[-1]` of the top-most layer (the one which outputs the output of the network).

`batch_first` puts the batch dimension before the time dimension (the default being the time dimension before the batch dimension), because the hidden state doesn't have a time dimension, `batch_first` has no effect on the hidden state shape.

Comment: This definitely should be part of the accepted answer, but it is not a complete answer (see the two questions in the text). I always try to ask questions here more general, so that as many people as possible can profit from the answer. Therefore it shouldn't really matter how many layers my specific network has (by the way, it has 3).

Comment: Wooops missed some of your questions. Edited and answered.